# Modifying contents of maketitle

Tags: titles, revtex

I am attempting to get a LaTeX style to match a journal's specification ([PDF](http://www.jsae.or.jp/taikai/manuscript_sample_e.pdf))

I have used a `revtex` document style with a number of tweaks, and I've gotten things close the desired output, but I'm stuck on some specific things created by the `\maketitle` command. My problems are very similar, so hopefully a solution to just one of them will point me towards how to answer all of them.

1. Is it possible to use the `\abstract{}` environment, but have it prefix the printed abstract with a bolded "ABSTRACT: " rather than just print the abstract?
2. There is a `\keywords{}` environment in `revtex`, but by default it displays "Keywords: " in the regular abstract font. I would like to modify this to match the journal's specifications (upper case, bolded)
3. Is it possible to change how the `\date{}` is displayed (ie, to change the prefix from "Dated: " to something like "Presented on..."

Code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,notitlepage,   %
    superscriptaddress,showkeys,nopacs,     %
    jmp,10pt]{revtex4-1}                    % "9pt" doesn't actually do anything because revtext has only 10,11,12pt

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Attempt to get a style or template working that matches requirements
% at the two links below:
% http://www.jsae.or.jp/taikai/manuscript_sample_e.pdf
% http://www.jsae.or.jp/taikai/manu_guide_e.pdf
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Various packages that I intend to use in my document - kept here to pre-empt package conflicts
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}                       % To produce tables with long text
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}  % http://www.howtotex.com/packages/automatic-clever-references-with-cleveref/
\usepackage{epstopdf}                       % http://tug.org/pipermail/texworks/2010q2/002895.html

%%% Set page margins
% Left, right, bottom margins set directly. Top margin set to 20mm + 5mm header-separation
\usepackage[left=18mm,top=20mm,right=18mm,bottom=25mm,includehead,nofoot,headheight=0pt,headsep=5mm]{geometry}

%%% Get numeration of headings with full context (ie, 2.1.3 SubSubsection)
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}}%
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}%
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}%
\def\theparagraph{\arabic{paragraph}}%
\def\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.\arabic{subparagraph}}%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}%

%%% Set heading font, style and placement
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\filcenter\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
%%% Set heading spacing
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{1.5em}{0.25em}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}

%%% Settings to explicitly place text in the top-right corner
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\TPGrid{14}{4}
\textblockorigin{194mm}{10mm} % Start 16mm from the right (210mm) paper edge, 10mm down


\begin{document}

%%% Selects "small" font. For 10pt articles, 9pt is the /small font size
\small

%%% Specify fonts for title and authors' text. The title gets the JSAE recieptNo attached to it.
\newcommand{\JSAEtitle}[1]{\title{\fontsize{10.95}{10.5}\selectfont \hspace{-100pt} \JSAEreceiptnoWprefix{}\hspace{10pt} \fontsize{17.28}{16}\selectfont \textmd{#1}}}
\newcommand{\JSAEauthor}[1]{\author{\fontsize{11}{11}\selectfont \textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\JSAEreceiptnoWprefix}{\JSAEreceiptnoPrefix{}-\JSAEreceiptno{}}

%%%%%%% USER INPUT %%%%%%%
% The user must place a JSAEreceiptno, JSAEreceiptnoPrefix, JSAEtitle, and any number of JSAEauthors.
\newcommand{\JSAEreceiptno}{00000000}
\newcommand{\JSAEreceiptnoPrefix}{000}
\JSAEtitle{A sample template for JSAE articles}

\JSAEauthor{J. T. Ripper}
\affiliation{Bethlem Royal Psychiatric Hospital\\
10-2 Gobancho, Chiyoda, Tokyo, 102-0076, Japan (E-mail: taro@jsar.or.jp)}
\JSAEauthor{Bugs Bunny}         \affiliation{Looney Tunes}
\JSAEauthor{Daffy Duck}         \affiliation{Looney Tunes}\affiliation{Warner Brothers}

%%%%%%% USER INPUT %%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract is here. \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

%%%%%%% USER INPUT %%%%%%%
\pacs{23.23.+x, 56.65.Dy}
\keywords{nuclear form; yrast level}
\date{December 2005}

\maketitle

%%% Place the JSAE receipt no in the top right corner
\begin{textblock}{2}[1,0](0,0)
\begin{flushright}
\fontsize{12}{12} \vspace{-10pt} \textbf{\JSAEreceiptno{}}
\end{flushright}
\end{textblock}

%%% Tweak the line spacing to match what seems to the be the spacing specification
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}

\section{Introduction}
The manuscript elements have been formatted for you 
through the “styles” capability of the software.  To use the styles, 
select the text you wish to apply a style to, then, using the mouse, 
point to the style box on the toolbar.  Click once on the 
downward pointing arrow to the right, and select the appropriate 
style.

\section{Methods}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[7]
\subsection{Next subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Now a subsubsection}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Results}
\lipsum[3-4]

\appendix
\section{Optional appendix}
The appendix section itself is optional and rarely used. The \verb+\appendix+ command signals that all following sections are appendices, 
so \verb+\section{title text}+ after \verb+\appendix +will set {title text} as an appendix heading (an empty {title text} is permitted).
For a single appendix, use a \verb+\appendix*+ followed by \verb+\section{title text}+ command to suppress the appendix letter in the section heading.

\end{document}
```

PS: I'm relatively new at trying to take control of final output... I recognise that much of what I've done could be seen as hacks to get nice looking output. I'd welcome suggestion on how to do things "better".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the keywords and the date you can say

```
\def\@keys@name{\textbf{KEYWORDS: }}
\def\Dated@name{Presented on: }
```

For the abstract you have to tell `revtex` some more things:

```
\@booleantrue\preprintsty@sw
\def\frontmatter@abstractheading{\noindent\textbf{ABSTRACT: }}
\g@addto@macro\abstract{\ignorespaces}
```

If the boolean `\preprintsty@sw` is false (as it is in your case), there's no heading for the abstract. Then we redefine the default heading, but we also need to make `abstract` ignore the end of line after it.

So, finally, the start of your document might be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,notitlepage,   %
    superscriptaddress,showkeys,nopacs,     %
    jmp,10pt]{revtex4-1}                    % "9pt" doesn't actually do anything because revtext has only 10,11,12pt


\makeatletter
\def\@keys@name{\textbf{KEYWORDS: }}
\def\Dated@name{Presented on: }
\@booleantrue\preprintsty@sw
\def\frontmatter@abstractheading{\noindent\textbf{ABSTRACT: }}
\g@addto@macro\abstract{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

Note, however, that `nopacs` and `jmp` return

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [nopacs,jmp].
```

so they should be removed.

---

In order to get the affiliation numbers like in the example, you can try adding also the following code before `\makeatother`, but I don't guarantee it's without side effects.

```
\def\frontmatter@makefnmark{\@thefnmark)~}
\def\@affil@present@script@#1{%
 \@ifx{\relax#1}{%
  \@ifx{\@tempa\@empty}{%
   \aftergroup\false@sw
  }{%
   \textsuperscript{\bfseries\expandafter\@affilcomma\@tempa\relax\relax}%
   \aftergroup\true@sw
  }%
 }{%
  \@ifnum{#1=\z@}{}{\appdef\@tempa{{#1)}}}%
  \@affil@present@script@
 }%
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed reply. One question, how would I go about finding these things like @keys@name and Dated@name?

Comment: @sven Those two are in `revtex4-1.cls`, I just searched for `Keywords` and `Dated`. For the abstract it was a bit more involved. Actually Sašo solution is perhaps easier

Comment: Ah yes, I see now that if I searched revtex4-1.cls for "Dated:" I would have found it.... I guess we're getting into "should know what you're doing" territory before I start messing around too much with that stuff :)

Can you perhaps point me to where in that file I'd find the little superscript affiliation number above each author? That's not something that has nicely searchable text to give it away... I'm thinking of putting a parentheses after each superscript...

Comment: @sven It's dangerous territory, yes. Those parentheses are awful, I'll try and see what can be done.

Comment: @sven I've added the code.

Comment: Yes, those parentheses are less than pretty... thanks very much for getting down to that detail too - it's certainly beyond my ability to parse yet but I'll get there one day! 

We'll see what happens when I submit a latexified PDF to this journal instead of using their MS word template! Hopefully it will either go unnoticed or they'll ask for the template too :)

Answer (score 4):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\abstract{\parindent 0pt \textbf{ABSTRACT: }\ignorespaces}
\makeatletter
\def\@keys@name{\textbf{KEYWORDS:} }
\def\Dated@name{Presented on }
\makeatother
```

Comment: What's `\xspace` for?

Comment: So that it doesn't matter whether the `abstract` environment starts with a space or not.

Comment: Not at all. You'll have a space nonetheless; `\xspace` never removes spaces.

Comment: duh! I meant `\ignorespaces`! Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks Saso, quick and works well. It was my first question here so I can't upvote yet... but when I can I will.