# Renaming date in revtex4

Tags: titles, datetime, revtex

I found the similar [question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97763/modifying-contents-of-maketitle/97769#97769) for renaming some of the keywords, but they were for revtex4-1. Since my document is giving me strange errors when I'm using revtex4-1, and not when I'm using revtex4, this solution didn't help.

I also found [a documentation](http://www.theochem.kth.se/docs/revtex4.pdf) about revtex4 and there I found this:

> The optional argument allows the user to override the text that will
>   be typeset along with the date; the default value of that text is
>   itself a localized macro.

```
1156\renewcommand*\date[2][\Dated@name]{\def\@date{#1#2}}%
1157\def\@date{}%
```

But this isn't working (or I don't understand how to use this)

Here's the 'mwe'

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,prb,floats,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,12pt]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipdfm,colorlinks=true,bookmarks=false,urlcolor=DarkOrchid,citecolor=ForestGreen,linkcolor=Cerulean,pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\makeatletter 
\gdef\@ptsize{0}% 10pt documents 
% or: 
%\gdef\@ptsize{1}% 11pt documents 
%\gdef\@ptsize{2}% 12pt documents 
\let\@currsize\normalsize 
\makeatother 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand*\date[2][\Dated@name]{\def\@date{#1#2}}%
\def\@date{Datum:}%

\renewcommand{\tocname}{Sadržaj}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\makeatother


\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}

\title{Random title}
\author{Random guy}
\affiliation{Random place, 99999 Randomville}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup


\section{Intro}

\section{Bla}

\subsection{Bla1}


\section{Bla!}


\end{document}
```

Comment: At least you need to do the `\renewcommand*\date[2]{...}` and `\def\@date{Datum:}` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to redefine `\date`, but only `\Dated@name`. Since this is an `@`-command, you need to enclose it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\Dated@name{Datum: }
\makeatother
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,prb,floats,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,nofootinbib,12pt]{revtex4}

\makeatletter
\def\Dated@name{Datum: }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Random title}
\author{Random guy}
\affiliation{Random place, 99999 Randomville}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to simply use

```
\date[Today: ]{\today}
```

The text within the square bracket replaces the "Dated" in revtex4-1 class. Enjoy!